# Avoid dependency of a pure code snippet package

Tags: nuget, code-snippets

Example: 
Nuget package A is a set of code snippets (it does not contain an assembly). 
Nuget package B is a normal assembly and it is using package A - just for internal means.

Question: What can I do, to avoid, that package A is also installed, when somone installes package B?

Comment: Are you in control of the source of both of these packages?

Comment: Yet I am in control of the source of both of these packages

Comment: I've looked into this a bit and I guess my initial memory of being able to do this is wrong. I thought you could compile the referenced package into the main one, but I'm not finding the steps on doing that. Your only choice seems to be importing the raw code snippets into your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something in documentation of nuget:

> Starting from version 2.7, the pack command will ignore  entries in the packages.config file which have an attribute developmentDependency set to true and will not include that package as a dependency in the created package. For example, consider the following packages.config file in the source project

That seems to solve the problem.